# Should I use A/B testing to find evidence that click-through rate has changed over four months?

Tags: dataset, ab-test

I am working with a toy data set. I have some data for a website over the last four months. This data includes how many times (and when) an ad was shown and how many times an ad (and when) was clicked. So, I can always calculate the ads-to-click rate over some time interval. For example, if a 100 ads were shown and there were 35 clicks over the first month, then my rate is $100/35$ [ads/click] over the first month.

My goal is to investigate if this rate is changing over the four months as a result of how the ads are being displayed on the website. Should I set up an A/B test with the first month's rate/data being the baseline, the second month being the first variation, the third month being the second variation, etc. ? I could count the number of trials (the number of times an ad was shown) and the number of successes (the number of times the ad was clicked) and then calculate the p-values for each variation. Is this the right way to go about my investigation?

Comment: I would have thought the *rate* was $35/100$.  You can certainly do something like what you are suggesting, but I would not all it *A/B testing*, which I would have thought meant showing different ads to different people in the same time period and comparing response rates

Comment: @Henry, Well, it doesn't really matter if you switch the numerator with the denominator. My concern is that I am dealing with data from different months, so I am wondering if there is anything better that I can do than this A/B testing (because there may be variables that I do not account for that differ from month to month).